# sharedPrefrences context null pointer, across activities

Tags: java, android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I've made an in app billing activity, successfully handling in app purchases, amongst querying purchases, which determines if an user is assigned ie. adblock.

Now I would like to run my method from the in app activity, in my main activity so i can query as soon as the app opens. However, i get a nullPointerException when i run that method, originating from a line consiting of `boolean adFree = mSharedPreferences.getBoolean(getString(R.string.remove_ads_key), false);`

My take on this, is that it's due to issues with the context, as I'm in the MainActivity, calling a method from InApp activity. Though i can't figure out how to fix this issue, and would appreciate any assistance you can offer.

```
//InApp Activity
    private SharedPreferences mSharedPreferences;
    private SharedPreferences.Editor mEditor;
    private Context context;
...

    public InApp(Context context){
    this.context = context;
}
...
    onCreate() {
    context = this;
    mSharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    mEditor = mSharedPreferences.edit();
}

 public void setupBillingClient(Context context){
        mBillingClient = BillingClient.newBuilder(context).setListener(this).enablePendingPurchases().build();
        mBillingClient.startConnection(new BillingClientStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onBillingSetupFinished(BillingResult billingResult) {
                if (billingResult.getResponseCode() == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK){
                    Log.i(TAG, "Billing Connected");
                    List<String> skuList = new ArrayList<>();
                    skuList.add(ITEM_SKU_ADREMOVAL);
                    SkuDetailsParams.Builder params = SkuDetailsParams.newBuilder();
                    params.setSkusList(skuList).setType(BillingClient.SkuType.INAPP);
                    mBillingClient.querySkuDetailsAsync(params.build(),
                            new SkuDetailsResponseListener(){
                                @Override
                                public void onSkuDetailsResponse(BillingResult billingResult, List<SkuDetails> skuDetailsList) {
                                    if (billingResult.getResponseCode() == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK && skuDetailsList != null){
                                        Log.i(TAG, "SkuDetailsResponse OK & skuDetailsList !=null - Contains: " + skuDetailsList.toString());
                                        for (SkuDetails skuDetails : skuDetailsList) {
                                            Log.i(TAG, "skuDetails: " + skuDetails.toString());
                                            Log.i(TAG, "skuDetailsList: " + skuDetailsList);
                                            String sku = skuDetails.getSku();
                                            String price = skuDetails.getPrice();
                                            skuDetails2 = skuDetails;
                                            Log.i(TAG, "SkuDetailsResponse found sku: " + sku);
                                            if (ITEM_SKU_ADREMOVAL.equals(sku)){
                                                adRemovalPrice = price;
                                                boolean adFree = mSharedPreferences.getBoolean(getString(R.string.remove_ads_key), false);
                                                if (adFree == false){
                                                    ad_button.setText(adRemovalPrice);
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            });
                }else{
                    Log.i(TAG, "setupBillingClient() ResponseCode: " + billingResult.getResponseCode());
                }
                //queryPurchases();

            }

//MainActivity
    static Context context;
...
    mSharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    mEditor = mSharedPreferences.edit();
...
    onCreate(){
    InApp inApp = new InApp(context);
    inApp.setupBillingClient(context);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must not call methods from other activities directly- nor create them or keep reference on them. Activity is created and managed by system, it is not POJO in any way. It has it's own lifecycle and can be destroyed in any moment and you has no control over it -https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#ActivityLifecycle
Because of it, app logic must be mainly decoupled from of framework classes and passed around to leverage actual tasks.

Comment: Thanks. So I should make a class which holds the methods for in app billing, and then call them from my InApp activity and main activity, is that correct?